# Can celery tasks instances be monitored by arbitrary identifiers?

Tags: python, celery

Is it possible to assign arbitrary identifiers to celery task instances - so that they can be monitored by these identifiers?

It would be useful to be able to track tasks by identifiers that are meaningful to the user.

Is there a standard pattern for something like this?

Comment: On your deleted question yesterday, we clashed considerably, and we probably each believe the other was responsible for escalating an argument. Shall we smoke a peace pipe, on the basis that fighting does not do any of us any good? `:-)`

Comment: Yes, sure. Not a problem.

Comment: Thanks! I hope you get the answer to your question. `halfer lights pipe`.